# vb.net Adding multi-valued string active directory query result to ArrayList object

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, active-directory

I'm struggling with a System.NullReferenceException error when trying to store the results of an Active Directory query in an ArrayList.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. My query is fetching the proxyAddresses attribute from a single AD account, then I use the following code to try to put that into an ArrayList I defined earlier:

```
For Each proxyAddr As String In result.Properties("proxyAddresses")
    proxyArrayList.Add(proxyAddr.Substring(0))
Next
```

This doesn't seem to work and the ArrayList remains empty even though I know there are valid results. I know this because the following works perfectly:

```
For Each proxyAddr As String In result.Properties("proxyAddresses")
    proxyListBox.Items.Add(proxyAddr.Substring(0))
Next
```

I'm sure I'm being daft, but I'm still trying to learn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use ArrayList. It's there for compatibility with old code, and for teaching purposes for students who haven't encountered generics yet. Real production code should always use List(Of T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you declared proxyArrayList like this:

```
Dim proxyArrayList As ArrayList
```

But you need to instantiate the ArrayList:

```
Dim proxyArrayList As New ArrayList
```

Comment: Oops! You're right there. Feeling very silly if it's just that, thanks I'll give it a go.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.